# get ALL capturing groups that matches with findall

Tags: python, regex

Hi I need a regexp to capture ALL the groups that matches a text

I have the following text

```
"abc"
```

and this regexp

```
compiled = re.compile("(?P<group1>abc)|(?P<group2>abc)")
compiled.findall("asd")
```

but the output is the following:

```
("abc", "")
```

The output I expect is the following

```
("abc", "abc") # one match per capturing group that matches
```

EDITED:

What I need to achieve

I have around 500 groups of things, and I want to categorize a text to each one of this groups, so I created a capturing group with a regexp for each one. in this way I can run a big regexp once, and get the index of the matched groups to know which group matched

for example, I have ingredients of desserts, and want to know to which desserts a text may belong:

```
test = re.compile('(?P<dessert1>(?:apple))|(?P<dessert2>(?:apple|banana))|(?P<others>(?:other))')
```

then if I have the string

```
apple
```

I would want to get the groups "desert1" and "desert2"
I can't run several regexps for each dessert for performance reasons

Comment: Only one alternative can match at a time.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I assume you want to match strings that may appear at the same position inside a string with some dynamic pattern. Probably, the posted solution can help, and you may use `(?=(?P<group1>abc)|(?P<group2>abc))` but this is not a good idea in general. You might need a different logic.

Comment: I added more context, probably I would need another approach, but using regexps was really fast, and it worked except for the case that two groups needs to match the same string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use a positive lookahead with one of the capturing groups

```
(?=(?P<group1>abc))(?P<group2>\1)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xHxBVR/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1NpD8i)

```
import re
 
regex = r"(?=(?P<group1>abc))(?P<group2>(?P=group1))"
test_str = "abc"
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Output

```
[('abc', 'abc')]
```

Or more explicit instead of the backreference `\1`, use `(?P=group1)` to match the same text as capturing group named `group1`

```
(?=(?P<group1>abc))(?P<group2>(?P=group1))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G9utid/1)

Comment: I added some clarification in my question, I'm not sure if I can use this solution